# want to use my own layout at ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I use the following code to use the ArrayAdapter for my ListView:

```
   ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
   String xml = ParseXMLMethods.getXML();
    Document doc = ParseXMLMethods.XMLfromString(xml);
    NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM); 
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {    


        Element e = (Element)children.item(i);
        mylist.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        mylist.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, KEY_CITY));
        mylist.add(ParseXMLMethods.getValue(e, KEY_COUNT));
    }
     adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     
     mylist);
     list2.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Here I am able to see only Title, but I want to see all three in my listView Row.For this I create another layout `R.layout.list_layout2` as follows:

**My layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:paddingLeft="6dp"
     >
     <TextView  
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:padding="1dp"
      android:textSize="16dp"
      android:textStyle="bold" 
      /> 
      <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
   <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/subtitle2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/subtitle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

How can I use this layout?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at a Custom ListView Adapter. Note that your original code uses a custom ListView but not the Adapter. You're going to want to create your own Adapter that extends ArrayAdapter since your ListView row is more complex than just one TextView.

See [Tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html) and [enter link description here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-list-in-android-applications-with-array-adapter/28038).

Ex:

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**CustomList.java**

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
   private final Activity context;
   private final String[] web;
   private final Integer[] imageId;
   public CustomList(Activity context, String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
      super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
      this.context = context;
      this.web = web;
      this.imageId = imageId;
   }
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);
      TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
      txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
      imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
      return rowView;
   }
}
```

In the example above, you're going to want to switch out the ImageView and replace it with your TextViews.

Comment: I had already used the above method but problem is that whenever I called this custom adapter at my main activity page it needs the array of KEY_TITLE,KEY_CITY,KEY_COUNT.unable to get this String array after XML parsing. also

Comment: In that case, it looks like your issue also has to do with XML parsing. What does your `mylist` ArrayList look like immediately following the last `.add` statement? Does it contain exactly what you're looking for? Secondly, if you have a complex ListView (i.e. more than one TextView) then you cannot simply use the base ArrayAdapter. You have to create a custom adapter as well. [See this tutorial for help](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-list-in-android-applications-with-array-adapter/28038).